# Synchronise function inside GlobalScope.launch(Main): Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Scenerio: let `fun A()` and `fun B()` be two functions. Inside `A()` we are calling `B(`). `B()` execution time takes around 5sec and meanwhile some other thread call A() again, then I am getting `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
fun A(){
  GlobalScope.launch(Main) {
    val result = withContext(IO) {
      B()
    }
    if (this@activity.isValid()) {
      suggestedFeedItems = result
    } else {

    }
  }
} 

fun B(){
   //some code that takes some time to execute
}
```

How to synchronise it so that at a time one thread can execute B(). I already tried to use `@synchronise`. As i m new in kotlin, Please suggest.

Comment: `Mutex.withLock` ? See https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/index.html

Comment: Better use an `Actor` to serialize processing.

Answer (score -1):

Problem seems to be exist in `fun B()`, where you might be doing loop in some `Collection` type (s.a. List, Stack...) **and** also deleting/inserting new element to that Collection type.

If that is the case, you should use `Iterator` to loop and you can delete/insert items while iterating. But if one thread is looping and other thread is inserting/deleting items, you need to synchronize access to that Collection type (using `@Synchronized fun B()` etc...).

Comment: Are `favoriteContacts` and `result` global variables or local? It looks like something Global is modified (rankedEvents.favorites etc...)